# Help combining options between two tcolourboxes

Tags: sectioning, tcolorbox, book-design

I have this code which allows me to define colours and style to my theorem style boxes depending on the section and I have the subsection code as well but I would like it so when the section changes colour the subsection continues in that colour scheme and in the style I have laid out, is this possible?

```
   \documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}               % Customize headers and footers
\usepackage{setspace}               % Adjust line spacing
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}            % Boxes for headings or text
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}                 % Customize chapter and section titles
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{libertine}                          % Use the Linux Libertine font (repeated)
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Counter definitions tied to section or chapter
\newcounter{thm}[section]
\newcounter{con}[section]


% Initialize current color with a default
\newcommand{\currentcolor}{colthm}

% Command to change the current color based on section
\newcommand{\changecolor}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\currentcolor}{#1}%
}

% Assuming you have a mechanism to distinguish section types, 
% you could redefine the \section command or create a new one to include the color change. 
% For simplicity, let's define custom commands for section types:
\newcommand{\thmsection}[1]{%
  \changecolor{colthm}%
  \section{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\consection}[1]{%
  \changecolor{colcon}%
  \section{#1}%
}
% Repeat for other types as needed

% Apply the current color to subsection titles
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{\currentcolor}} % Format
  {\thesubsection}{0.5em}{} % Label and separation


% Custom formatting for counters
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\thechapter.\thesection.\arabic{thm}}
\renewcommand{\thecon}{\thechapter.\thesection.\arabic{con}}


% Color definitions for different box types
\colorlet{colthm}{red!90!black}
\colorlet{colcon}{blue!70!white}
\colorlet{coldefin}{green!50!black!50}
\colorlet{colpost}{green!80!white!50}
\colorlet{colcn}{orange!80!black!10}

% The main command to create a styled tcolorbox
\newcommand{\newmybox}[4]{%
  \tcbset{
    #1base/.style={ 
      enhanced,                % Use enhanced features for the box
      breakable,               % Allow box to break across pages
      empty,                   % No background and frame by default
      frame engine=path,       % Use path-based rendering for the frame
      colframe=yellow!10,      % Frame color (not visible with empty style)
      sharp corners,           % Sharp corners, can be customized
      title={#2 \thechapter.\thesection.\arabic{#3}}, % Box title format
      attach boxed title to top left={yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight},
      boxed title style={size=minimal, top=4pt, left=4pt, colback=#4},
      coltitle=black,          % Title text color
      fonttitle=\large\bfseries\sffamily, % Title font style
      drop fuzzy shadow=black!50!white, % Uncomment for shadow effect
      borderline west={3pt}{-3pt}{#4}, % Border line on the left
      attach boxed title to top left={xshift=3mm, yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
      boxed title style={right=3pt, bottom=3pt, overlay={
        \draw[draw=#4, fill=#4, line join=round] 
        (frame.south west) -- (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) --
        (frame.south east) -- ++(-2pt, 0) -- ++(-2pt, -4pt) --
        ++(-2pt, 4pt) -- cycle;
      }},
    },
  }
  \newtcolorbox[use counter=#1]{#1}{%
    #1base, % Apply the base style
    % Additional styles or parameters can be added here
  }
}
% Revised command to ensure proper text wrapping
\newtcolorbox{boxsubsect}[2][]{
  enhanced,
  before skip=2mm, after skip=2mm,
  colframe=blue!50!black, colback=yellow!20!white,
  colbacktitle=red!5!white,
  breakable, % Ensures content can break across pages/lines
  fonttitle=\bfseries\small,
  coltitle=black,
  width=\linewidth, % Explicitly set the width to the line width
  left=1mm, right=1mm, % Adjust padding as necessary
  attach boxed title to top left={
    yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,
    yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/3
  },
  boxed title style={
    boxrule=0.4mm,
    frame code={
      \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-0mm]frame.west)--(frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=3mm]frame.east)
      -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle;
    },
    interior code={
      \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-0mm]interior.west)--(interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)
      -- ([xshift=1.5mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west)
      -- cycle;
    },
  },
  title={\thesubsection #2}, #1,
  valign=center, % This ensures vertical alignment; adjust as needed
}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Roman{subsection}.}

% Adjusted title format for subsection to ensure the box is used correctly
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {} % Preceding the title body
  {}{0em} % Space between label and title body, if any
  {\begin{boxsubsect}{\hskip0.7em#1}\end{boxsubsect}} % Before the title
  [] % After the title

% Command to easily create new theorem-like environments
\newcommand{\newmythm}[3]{%
  \newmybox{#1}{#2}{#3}{col#1}%
}

% Creating specific environments
\newmythm{thm}{Theorem}{thm}
\newmythm{con}{Construction}{con}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

    \begin{thm}
        Theorem
    \end{thm}
        \subsection{Wrong colour}

    \begin{con}
        Construction
    \end{con}
        \subsection{wrong colour}

\end{document}
```